Predictive dataset at three time points: prediction, decision, and outcome
I am looking for datasets in any domain that has at least three clear, unambiguous time points: prediction, decision, and outcome. This is rather unusual, so please explain the lengthy background to explain just what I'm looking for.
A close case to what I'm looking for is the famous Bank Marketing dataset: "The data is related with direct marketing campaigns (phone calls) of a Portuguese banking institution. The classification goal is to predict if the client will subscribe a term deposit (variable y)." Here, the decision of interest would be whether bank agents should call a customer to propose a term deposit or not. This decision is costly; for example, it might cost €5 to €15 per call, depending on how long it lasts. So the entire purpose of the predictive project is to estimate those customers who are likely to say "yes" so the bank can call them and estimate those likely to say "no" so the bank will not waste time and money calling them (and also so the bank does not bother people who are not interested). For everyone who is not predicted to say "yes", the bank can just send an email offer: while email is much less effective, it costs the bank almost nothing, so they might get a few unexpected subscriptions that way.
I will use the Bank Marketing dataset as an example to clarify what I am looking for (and why it does not quite meet my needs).
Prediction (T1). Most variables will be in Time 1 and are used to predict the outcome. For example, the Bank Marketing dataset has age, job, education, loan, etc. as the main predictors for the outcome y.
Outcome (T3). This is the ultimate predictive target outcome of interest. I am interested in any kind of outcome: classification, regression, survival, etc. For the Bank Marketing dataset, the outcome y is whether the customer subscribes or not to a term deposit. In most datasets set up for prediction, the outcome is in Time 2 (T2), a timeframe distinctly after the T1 prediction variables. What is unusual in my request is the decision step.
Decision (T2). This step comes between the typical predictors (T1) and the outcome (T3) of most predictive datasets. The idea here is that some decision-maker (e.g., a manager, user, clinician, etc.) makes a decision based on the information from the T1 predictors that directly impacts the ultimate T3 outcome.
In the Bank Marketing case, the relevant decision is whether to call a customer or not. So, the bank does not jump directly from predictors to outcome--there is the intermediary decision of whether to call a customer or not. A customer cannot have a "yes" subscription outcome if they are not called at all. The Bank Marketing dataset only includes data for all customers who were called. There is no data available for customers who were not called nor any indication why some were called and some were not. This would be the valuable Decision (T2) data that is missing.
(In fact the Bank Marketing dataset is particularly interesting because it includes data for a previous campaign in which some of the customers participated, previous and poutcome. However, the dataset does not specify if the customers who were not previously contacted were even available for the previous campaign, so it does not provide accurate Decision (T2) data as I am seeking here.)
So, for the Bank Marketing dataset to meet my needs, it would need:

Add a variable like called ("yes" or "no") that indicates whether a customer was called or not.
Include full data for customers who were called for the current marketing campaign as well as those whom the bank decided not to call.

Here is why this structure of data would be valuable:

Prediction (T1): These variables are used to advise a decision that needs to be made at Decision time (T2).

Decision (T2): These variables (probably just one or two) are used to evaluate the Outcome (T3) result given the Decision (T2) made based on the Prediction (T1) information.

Outcome (T3): The ultimate outcome of interest does not depend directly on the predictor variables; it depends directly on some intervention or decision, based indirectly on the predictor variables.


So, data thus structured should be able to guide more effective decisions.
Can you point me to any available datasets with this structure of data? I am interested in literally any domain: business, healthcare, natural science, engineering, anything as long at it matches this structure.
